# How l can call values() from instance of generic type <E extends Enum<E>>?

Tags: java, generics, enums

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> void example(E e){
    e. //what should I put here to get result of values()?
}
```

I am trying to call the method `values()` that returns the values of an `enum` using this method with generic arguments.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Enum` doesn't have `values()` method. It is added by compiler later to each of your Enum subclasses (when we are creating our own `enum YourEnum{...}` type). So we can't invoke `values()` from `Enum` type.

Possible solution is

```
E[] values = e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants();
```

To be safe we should use `getDeclaringClass()` instead of `getClass()`, because enum values can be implemented as *anonymous classes* like in case of [`TimeUnit`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.java#71)

```
public enum TimeUnit {
    /**
     * Time unit representing one thousandth of a microsecond
     */
    NANOSECONDS {
        public long toNanos(long d)   { return d; }
        public long toMicros(long d)  { return d/(C1/C0); }
        public long toMillis(long d)  { return d/(C2/C0); }
        public long toSeconds(long d) { return d/(C3/C0); }
        public long toMinutes(long d) { return d/(C4/C0); }
        public long toHours(long d)   { return d/(C5/C0); }
        public long toDays(long d)    { return d/(C6/C0); }
        public long convert(long d, TimeUnit u) { return u.toNanos(d); }
        int excessNanos(long d, long m) { return (int)(d - (m*C2)); }
    },
```

In this case

- `TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.getClass()` returns `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit$3` (but this anonymous class doesn't contain any enum values)
- `TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.getDeclaringClass()` returns `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` (with contains all of enum values).

It will also save us some trouble with casting since

- `getDeclaringClass` returns `Class<E>`
- `getClass()` returns `Class<? extends E>`

So result type of

- `getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants()` is `E[]`
- while `getClass().getEnumConstants()` is `? extends Enum[]`.

This allows us to create loop like without need to involve casting:

```
for (E value : e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants()){
    //handle value
}
```

---

As an extra, you can also get all values from `Class<E>` (where `<E extends Enum<E>>`) by using `EnumSet.allOf(enumClass)` like in case of code from this question:

```
EnumSet<E> allOf = EnumSet.allOf(e.getDeclaringClass());
```

Comment: Interesting side note: `getEnumConstants()` is actually implemented by [calling `values()` in the enum class via reflection](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/96393e490afd/src/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java#l3307). :-) (The reflection happens only once per class: the values are cached, and `getEnumConstants()` returns a defensive copy of those values on each call.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a method in the clas `Class<T>` called `getEnumConstants()` which does just that. So i had this method that printed out the enum constants given any enum value here:

```
public <E extends Enum<E>> void printEnums(E e){
    for(E value : e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants()){
        System.out.println("Value: "+value);
    }
}
```

To call it i would use something like
`printEnums(Enum.SOME_VALUE);`

although I think the following method is better because it takes as parameter the class of the enum directly:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> void printEnums(Class<E> e){
    for(E value : e.getEnumConstants()){
        System.out.println("Value: "+value);
    }
}
```

You can call this method like so: `printEnums(EnumClass.class);`

I know you are not asking how to print the enum values, but these methods above are good to give you a headstart on how to access the constants given the type or the class.

**EDIT 1:** Changed the code. Thanks @JBNizet

**EDIT 2:** Changed the code again according to @Tunaki's comment. Note: this was initially adressed on [Pshemo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765777/how-l-can-call-values-method-in-this-situation/37765856#37765856)

Comment: The type of `value` should be E, not Enum<E>. Also, e.getClass() should be cast to Class<E> (its declared return type is Class<?>)

Comment: @JBNizet You are absolutely right! I am editing this imidiately! Thank you for pointing that out :o

Comment: The first snippet does not work in all cases, try with `printEnums(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`. See [Pshemo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37765856/1743880), you need to use `getDeclaringClass()`

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks i included that in the answer. I didn't imagine that to be honnest!

Comment: It's a bit of a corner-case yes. Note that with this change, you don't need the cast anymore, you can just have `for (E value : e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants())`.

Comment: @Tunaki Thank you! :)