# Get Values of variables under an Enum

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I want to write into a file/print the constants of an enum, as well as the values of their variables.

For example, here is what I thought of doing:

```
id, field_name_1, field_name_2, ...
enum_id, field_value_1, field_value_2, ...
...
```

However, I am not fully sure on how to do such a thing, as I only recently began working with reflection.

This is the code that I currently have.

```
public static void writeEnum(String filename, Enum e, SnelPlugin plugin){
        SnelTextFile file = new SnelTextFile(plugin, new File(plugin.getDataFolder() + "/" + filename + ".txt"));
        Logger.debug("Starting an EnumWriter for " + filename + ".txt for plugin " + plugin.getPluginName());

    try {
        file.openWriter(true);

        Field[] fields = e.getClass().getFields();

        // HEADER
        String info = "";
        for(Field f: fields) {
            info += ", " + f.getName();
            Logger.debug("Detected value: " + f.getName());
        }
        info = info.replaceFirst(", ", "");
        file.addLine(info);

        // CONTENT
        for(Object current: e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants()){
            Logger.debug(current.toString());

            String result = "";

            for(Field f: fields){
                result += ", " + f.get(current);
            }

            result = result.replaceFirst(", ", "");

            file.addLine(result);

            Logger.debug("Added row: " + result);
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            file.closeWriter();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        }
    }

    Logger.log(LColor.GREEN + "Finished an EnumWriter action on " + filename + ".txt from " + plugin.getPluginName());
}
```

Here is the Enum (APIPerm), which I setup for a simple test:

```
COMMANDS_SNELAPI,
COMMANDS_SNELAPI_INFO;

private String id;

APIPerm(){
    id = getID();
}

@Override
public String getPrefix() {
    return "snelapi";
}

@Override
public String getID(){
    return getPrefix() + "." + this.toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("_", ".");
}
```

However, I get an NPE in `for(Object current: e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants())`

Thanks for your help,
Sneling.

Comment: Please test what is null in the for statement - e or the return value of getEnumConstants(). I bet e is null and something goes wrong before/during the call of writeEnum(). Since the method argument e is definitely an enum, and the example in your png file seems to have actual enum constants, getEnumConstants() should not return null.

Comment: @MarkusFischer if `e` was null then we would get NPE earlier. So it looks like `getEnumConstants()` is culprit. But that also doesn't make much sense since OP requires from `e` to be *instance* of some Enum, so that enum must have at last one enum constant (the one passed as argument).

Comment: Yes, that's why I was very disturbed about why this happened. At the same time, I'd rather have a call for values() to parse through as it would be easier (i think?) to get the information the Enum. Then again, if you guys have another method to do so, i'd love it. This is temporary, as at a later date I will make them 'print' into an excel table.

Comment: @Pshemo You are right, I overlooked the previous usage of e - it can't be null at that point.

Comment: I am not sure how to help you since I don't know exactly what results you are expecting and I can't reproduce NPE problem from your question. So post example of input/enum class you want to handle (but don't post it as picture, we can't copy that to our IDEs). Include your expected results (you can add some info about why they are expected) and what you get instead. Also reduce your code, if `SnelPlugin` is not required, then don't include it in code. Also not everyone here may have logging mechanism configured, so why not use simple `System.out` instead?

Comment: @Sneling Passing the enum values() and processing is of course a valid solution. However, it's puzzling where the NPE comes from. Is this plain stand-alone Java, or is it within a framework of any kind? Is there a chance that framework functionality is manipulating your classes?

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks for your help! I posted an update on my question with updated code, wit hwhat you guys have asked for. 
I feel like I am missing something very important, but as I am new with reflection, I am not sure what exactly. Would, for example, 'COMMANDS_SNELAPI' would be considered as an Enum with its own variables? If yes, then would having a way to easily get the "Enum Class" help me parse through the enums, and then from there get the fields? If yes, I would assume that there might be a way to get the Fields in the "Enum Class" by default?
Thanks.

Comment: If you are asking how to get enum values like how to get from `enum MyEnum{FOO, BAR;}` values `FOO` and `BAR` but passing any of that value, then you can pass Class representing this enum `Class<MyEnum>` (you can get it via `MyEnum.class`). Then assuming that your method is accepting `Class<E> c` (where `E` is method's generic type `<E extends Enum<E>>`) you can call `c.getEnumConstants()` and get `E[]` array containing all enums (just like `values()`). DEMO: https://ideone.com/tJ5qAt (my previous answer on that subject http://stackoverflow.com/a/37765856/1393766)

Comment: But what I am not sure if getting enums is all you want. Like what about fields? Each enum constant may have its own values in fields (like id) from one of your previous examples. Do you also want to handle it? If so how?

Comment: @Pshemo What I want to do is be able to 'see' the value of every field for each E. For example, here, i'd like it to print the field 'id', or at least it should show me something like it would see the 'id'. (https://ideone.com/y0dCNJ) I looked at your other post, which has already the beginning of the code, but i'm still stuck with getting the different variables for each E.
To be precise, I want to be able to read every fields for every E. So, from my code I sent you in this comment, I would expect to get:
http://pastebin.com/2SpGWuYs

Comment: So it looks like you want to get all (not only public ones) fields which are not static (since they should belong to instance, not class). In that case you may may want to use `getDeclaredFields()` instead of `getFields()`. Difference is that `getFields` returns only public fields, including inherited ones, while `getDeclaredFields()` returns only fields *declared* in that class (including even private ones - so if you want to `get` value of that field you may need to invoke earlier `setAccessible(true)` on them). DEMO: https://ideone.com/qVkHIg

Comment: @Pshemo Oh, ok! That actually is exactly what I was looking for. I tried with your method, which worked, now I will try to implement in in the method that I already have, and see what it gives. If it works well, would you want me to post the full answer to my question and tag you in it, or would you rather do it yourself?
FIY, I have full working method, but it contains both SnelPlugin and my Logger.

Comment: If it is possible try to simplify your question like "I would like to print each enum constant, and if that enum has its fields, values of that fields for each of that constants, for example [post enum structure and expected results]. I tried with this code [post simple code showing your approach - "simple" like avoid unnecessary things like writing to file when we can simply write to console] but problem is that [describe problem you are facing, like fact you don't want method to accept instance, since some enums may be empty and you want to be also able to handle them]".

Comment: Also IMO there is no need for these `Update #X` versions. We are not forum, we expect one specific question per ... question which can be answered reasonably. So as long as you are adding more information it is OK to skip that UPDATE part.

Comment: Now if that linked code worked for you and question will be updated in a way that this code will answer it directly feel free to post it as your own answer (I don't mind), or let me know and I will post it as my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Pshemo and @MarkusFisher, I've come to a solution.

Note that this method DOES include other classes and methods, but they don't affect the way this method works.

If you want to test for yourself:

- Logger.debug can be replaced with System.out.println, LColor should
  be deleted
- SnelPlugin is only needed for the Logger.debug and locating a directory.
- SnelTextFile is just a class to make creating text files easier. Remove if you're only printing.

Method Code:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> void writeEnum(String fileName, Class<E> c, SnelPlugin plugin){
    SnelTextFile file = new SnelTextFile(plugin, new File(plugin.getDataFolder() + "/" + fileName + ".txt"));
    Logger.debug("Starting EnumWriter for " + file.getFile().getName(), plugin);

    try {
        file.openWriter(true);
        Logger.debug("Opened FileWriter", plugin);

        Field[] classFields = c.getDeclaredFields();

        String header = "Value";

        for(Field f: classFields){
            if(!Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())) {
                header += ", " + f.getName();
                Logger.debug("Discovered variable '" + f.getName() + "'", plugin);
            }
        }

        file.addLine(header);
        file.addLine("");

        for(E en: c.getEnumConstants()){
            Logger.debug("Reading Enum Constant: " + en.toString(), plugin);
            Field[] fields = en.getDeclaringClass().getDeclaredFields();

            String current = en.toString();

            for(Field f: fields){
                if(!Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())){
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                    current += ", " + f.get(en);
                    Logger.debug("Value for '" +f.getName() + "' = '" +  f.get(en) + "'" , plugin);
                }
            }

            file.addLine(current);
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            file.closeWriter();
            Logger.debug("Closer FileWriter");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }

    Logger.log(LColor.GREEN + "Finished EnumWriter for " + file.getFile().getName() + ". It can be found at " + file.getFile().getPath(), plugin);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the values of the Enum, normally you would just call the `values()` method on the Enum class.  But since you are starting with an instance you need to get the class and call it.  I don't see any way to just cast the class to Enum, so I used reflection to get the `public static Enum[] values()` method like this.

```
/**
 * Get the Enum values for this Enum instance.
 * @param e the enum value
 * @return all the values for this type of enum
 */
private Enum[] getValues(Enum e) {
    Enum[] values = new Enum[0];
    try {
        Class<? extends Enum> enumClass = e.getDeclaringClass();
        Method mtd = enumClass.getMethod("values");
        values = (Enum[])mtd.invoke(null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return values;
}
```

Obviously you should do better error handling.  I am not sure what else you wanted from the Enum class in regards to fields.

Comment: Hey, 
Thanks for your suggestion. My only little question is from where would I get the instance of the Enum, as the goal of an Enum is not having to do this(...?)? I tested a new thing without your function, but I would sure love to see how you would use it in full depth. Please check my new update on the original post.

Comment: In your code one of the arguments is ```Enum e``` so I assumed you had the instance and not the class.  If you have the enum class then you can just call ```values()``` directly.

Comment: Why not take the class and do EnumSet.allOf instead?